# How to create Text file and write exceptions in it automatically using Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

i am using selenium web-driver in c#, i want to Create a text/ log file and write exception in it automatically.
right now i am doing testing on log in page. if i change the password then the exception should be written in text file with time stamp.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using log4net ( http://logging.apache.org/log4net/ ) it's a pretty straight forward logging library. Selenium doesn't really have any impact on your logging. You handle exceptions the same and put logging statements in the catch's as you normally would.